# Is it possible to check if a trait's object has been initialized yet?

Tags: scala

I have a trait such as

```
trait MyTrait {
  // blah
}

object MyTrait {
  // Check to see if OtherTrait has been used/initialized yet
  try {
    val c = Class.forName("...OtherTrait")
    println("found " + c.getName)
    . . .
  } catch {
    case classNotFoundException : ClassNotFoundException =>
      println("ClassNotFoundException: " + classNotFoundException.getMessage)
  }
}
```

What would the code look like to see OtherTrait's object has been initialized yet, such that I don't want to initialize it as a side effect of the check?

This seems like a reflection thing, and I know how to check Class.forName to see if "...OtherTrait" is available from the class-loader, but even if the class-loader can find it, I want to know if it has been initialize yet. That is, I don't want to use it if not one else has used it yet.

Comment: What is the bigger picture here?  Could you explain why you don't want your trait to be the first to use this other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using another object to track the trait's initialization status?

```
object OtherTraitMarker {
  private var _isInitialized = false
  def isInitialized = _isInitialized
  private[OtherTrait] def initialize() = _isInitialized = true
}

trait OtherTrait {
 ... expensive work
 OtherTraitMarker.initialize
}

object MyTrait {
  // Check to see if OtherTrait has been used/initialized yet
  if (OtherTraitMaker.isInitialized) {
    // do some work
  }
}
```

[Note that I respectfully but strongly disagree with the dictate made by another responder that one should never modify state in class initialization blocks. That's exactly why initialization blocks **exist**. What would be the point of them otherwise?]

Comment: Thanks, that is really simple, no reflection needed, works like a charm for my application.

Basically I have a bunch of initialization traits, the log some output. If my trait LogbackLogging is initialized, then I use logger.info(), otherwise I use println(). I want users to have a choice if they are using Logback, or some other logging method.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should never put a code with side effects in a class initialization block. If the code relies on a class initialization order or stuff like that it violates all existing programming paradigms.

2) If you really need to check it you can traverse all .jar archives in a classpath and try to find a class. Of course it works only for classes loaded  from classpath.